# Where can i modify username validation in Freeradius 3x?

Tags: freeradius

I want to remove username existing validation from free-radius server and will add our custom validation for username. Can you please tell where can i get that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy is defined in [raddb/policy.d/filter](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/policy.d/filter) and called from [raddb/sites-available/default](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/raddb/sites-available/default#L292).